# UIWebview doesen't display PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have used this code for displaying PDF on webview.

```
webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fonts1" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webview loadRequest:request];
webview.scalesPageToFit=YES;

[self.view addSubview:webview];
```

PDF in bundle I get PDF correctly.

What is wrong in this code.

Comment: you are getting PDF from server or Local?

Comment: Local pdf present in my bundle

Comment: See my answer and try it.

Comment: I had just copied your code and run. It's working fine. Only thing i changed is PDF Name. and set the delegate

Answer (score 0):

try below one

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: please put NSLog for NSURL .

Comment: what the result of NSLOG(@"%@", targetURL);

Answer (score 0):

If it is local then just put

```
    UIWebView *WebViewObj = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];        
    [self.view addSubview:WebViewObj];
    [self.WebViewObj loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display a PDF file residing on a server somewhere, you can simple load it to your web view directly:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Or if you have a PDF file bundled with your application (in this example named "document.pdf"):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

if i add

UIWebView *

at the beginning of your code everything works fine already tested

i dont think that is your problem

you should check the name of the file maybe is misspelled or check if the pdf file appears with red letters

if red letters the file is missing/damaged/moved

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think your pdf file not in target member so remove file and add like below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

sagarcool89,SAMIR RATHOD,and dhaya: Every one given the right solutions:

```
UIWebView *pdfDisplay = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IHI0053A_acle" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    [pdfDisplay loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pathURL]];
    [self.view addSubview:pdfDisplay];
```

and it's the correct way to load pdf file in uiwebview.